# Transfer Data from One Table to Another or else Update the Data

Tags: mysql

Good Afternoon. I have two Tables and they are

Table: GeneralInventory

[image]

and Table: Receiving

[image]

As you can see this formats on Table are most likely you will see in Inventory System, My Table `GeneralInventory` is the Main Inventory where all Items that you will received will transfer here and that Table is `Receiving` as what you see in the table `Receiving` there 2 Data and they are.

[image]

Please be focused on the **RINo** field they are Different right? now here is what I will do and also my Question (I will convert my Question in Step by Step procedure of the Program)

1. The Program will Select 1(One) Data from Table `Receiving`
2. I will click a button named `Post` and the Program will do the Following

   -Check if the `ItemCode` of the Selected `RINo` already Exist in the Table                              `GeneralInventory` and If the `ItemCode`  is already in there then `ReceivedQty` of table `Receiving` and `Qty` of Table `GeneralInventory` will sum up or else add the Data.

I hope you get my point but if not I will show you further Example.

[image]

In General: If the Data Exist then Sum it Up or Else add the New Data.

I am using this Code.

```
INSERT INTO GeneralInventory (ItemCode, Qty)
SELECT RE.ItemCode, RE.ReceivedQty
FROM Receiving RE LEFT JOIN
     GeneralInventory GI
ON   GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND GI.Qty = RE.ReceivedQty
WHERE RE.RINo = 'Data of RINo'

UPDATE GeneralInventory GI
INNER JOIN receiving RE
    ON GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND GI.Qty = RE.ReceivedQty
SET GI.Qty = GI.Qty + RE.ReceivedQty RE.RINo = 'Data of RINo'
```

TY for future Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Answer (score -1):

```js
@
query = select * from GeneralInventory GI
inner join Receiving RE
on GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode
where RE.RINo = 'YOUR-VARIABLE'
if (@query) {
  UPDATE GeneralInventory GI INNER JOIN receiving RE ON GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND GI.Qty = RE.ReceivedQty SET GI.Qty = GI.Qty + RE.ReceivedQty RE.RINo = 'Data of RINo'
} else {
  NSERT INTO GeneralInventory(ItemCode, Qty) SELECT RE.ItemCode, RE.ReceivedQty FROM Receiving RE LEFT JOIN GeneralInventory GI ON GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND GI.Qty = RE.ReceivedQty WHERE RE.RINo = 'Data of RINo'
}
```

Hi use this above query ..

Comment: 1. What language / syntax does the above code snippet use? 2. You can do the above in a single sql statement if you have the appropriate index defined.

Comment: @
query = select * from GeneralInventory GI
inner join Receiving RE
on GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode
where RE.RINo = 'YOUR-VARIABLE'
if (@query) {
  UPDATE GeneralInventory GI INNER JOIN receiving RE ON GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND GI.Qty = RE.ReceivedQty SET GI.Qty = GI.Qty + RE.ReceivedQty RE.RINo = 'Data of RINo'
} else {
  INSERT INTO GeneralInventory(ItemCode, Qty) SELECT RE.ItemCode, RE.ReceivedQty FROM Receiving RE LEFT JOIN GeneralInventory GI ON GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND GI.Qty = RE.ReceivedQty WHERE RE.RINo = 'Data of RINo'
}